Installing Spring Tools 4 into an existing Eclipse Instance in 2024
I am trying to install Spring Tools 4 into an existing Eclipse Install (2024-12). I can not use the packaged Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse that is available for download from here due to organizational security requirements for that workstation.
When I tried to install using the Eclipse Marketplace I received a error that the artifact osgi.bundle org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls could not be downloaded. I also noticed that the update site https://cdn.spring.io/spring-tools/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.34/ is offline with a 404 from Cloudflare.
I have had this issue since October of 2024. My workaround has been to use a old Eclipse instance (2023-12) with the Spring Tools 4 plugin already installed. This workaround is going to become broken due to organizational security requirements for that workstation.
I suspect the root cause is https://cdn.spring.io/spring-tools/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.34/ is offline or improperly configured but I want to make sure it is not a issue on my end before I reach out to VMware/Broadcom.
I have tested this on both on the restricted workstation at work and on my personal unrestricted computer at home and experienced the same results.
The packaged Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse that I downloaded from here works fine on my personal computer but is not a option for the restricted workstation that this issue is for.
I have tried this in Eclipse 2023-12 and Eclipse 2024-06 with the same results.
I have also looked at STS4 Installation Page on the Wiki. This solution did not work in this case either system.
I have looked at this Stack Overflow issue.
Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

https://cdn.spring.io/spring-tools/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.34 only gives a 404 error to web browsers. As a update site, it does seem to contain org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls, so perhaps try that with the Install New Software wizard?

@nitind I Just tried this on the restricted system from the Install New Software wizard for just the Spring Boot Language Server and got the same error.
Is there any way to take a look at what is in that repository and see the download links it is providing?

eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -list -repository https://cdn.spring.io/spring-tools/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.34. Also, try it with all of the main features.

@nitind I Just tried this both of my systems (Both Windows). In both cases I did see the eclipse splash screen but did not see any output on the console. Where should I look for the output? I am also trying the Spring install again on the restricted system.

@nitind I did add -consolelog to the end which did give me output in a new terminal window but I was not able to read it before it closed.

@nitind Thanks for your help. I was able to isolate the issue to a network connectivity problem that impacted my link to one of the mirrors.

After doing additional troubleshooting I managed to isolate it to 2 different network issues that both resulted in connectivity issues to one of the mirrors.
On my personal computer my ISP was not able to route traffic to the mirror that hosted the artifact. On my personal computer I was able to fix this using a VPN during the install.
On my restricted workstation the issue was the security system was not allowing access to the mirror that hosted the artifact.
The problem was 2 different simultaneous network issues on both of my environments that resulted with the same symptoms.
